# error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c

Getting error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive] 
>   on g++

on the following code:

```
void* func(void *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    int self = (int *)s;
    printf("Thread Entered: %d\n", self);

    sm.lock(self);

    // Critical section (Only one thread
    // can enter here at a time)
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        ans++;

    sm.unlock(self);
}
```

Comment: What should `int self = (int *)s;` do? You're literally doing what the error says.

Comment: You need to show the code that starts this thread, inclining any relevant variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `int self = (int *)s;` to `int self = *((int *)s);` or to `int * self = (int *)s;`.

Comment: Too early to answer this one. You can't be sure any of your suggestions are correct until more information shows up. Personally I suspect it will turn out to be `int self = (int)s;`, but have no good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think of these as two different things.  One is a pointer to memory where the value is stored (`int*`) and the other is an actual value (`int`).

<strike>Looking at your function declaration `void* func(void *s)`, your `s` parameter is of type `void`, this will need to be `int` if you wish to convert it.</strike>

Your data types seem a bit mixed, which just doesn't fly do well in C/C++.  <strike>Can you clean it?</strike>  If you are using this function with `pthread_create()`, as per the documentation with example for this function, try..

```
// your pthread_create call..
int SOME_INT = 123;
s = pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, &thread_start, &SOME_INT);

//...and your function
void* func(void *s)
{
    int self = (int*) s;
```

Pointers can be confusing.  See if that above code looks similar, in particular to passing the last parameter for `pthread_create` as a pointer reference.   And then try your original code.  It might just be that it wasn't passed as a reference.

See what that yields you, else try storing it as a pointer and then converting on use.

```
void* func(void *s)
{
    int *self = s;

    sm.lock(*self);  // but can give a potential race condition.
```

Comment: The signature `void* func(void *s)` is required by [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), so not anything you can do much about.

Comment: You may need to reconsider how you are passing the data.  Your void pointer could potentially mean anything, and if you access it incorrectly, then you may start reading some other program's memory space, which would cause your program to crash randomly with a '_General Protection Fault_' (Windows) or '_Segment Fault_' (Linux).

Comment: My guess is that `pthread_create` is using an unusual methodology for passing un-typed data, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: According to the docs you linked, it creates the thread as such  `pthread_create(&tinfo[tnum].thread_id, &attr, &thread_start, &tinfo[tnum])`, where `&tinfo[tnum]` (your `void *s` component) passes a `thread_info` structure, which is then accessed via the thread function with `struct thread_info *tinfo = arg;`.  If you are calling the `pthread_create`, check that these match likewise.  Will update the answer to include an example.